# Make text vertical center and perfect responsive squares

Tags: css, responsive-design, vertical-alignment, responsive

I know this question has been asked in variation, but i'm trying to both align the **text vertically and horizontally**, **and** also make the **square responsive as a perfect square**. I'm really close, but when you view full screen, and put the page in responsive mode, the squares become rectangles. How can I make them perfect squares and maintain alignment?

here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/fussinhussin/pen/oqzLjV?editors=1100)

css:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 10%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 110%;
  padding-bottom: 85%;
  margin: 1.66%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box-col {
  background: purple;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box {
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px;
  resize: vertical;
  width: 100%
}
```

html:

```
<!-- made with bootstrap -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col box-col">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="content">
          Cruisin shade with my squad.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col box-col">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="content">
          Bounce Bounce.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col box-col">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="content">
          Cactus be sharp, but the juice be good.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col box-col">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="content">
          I like ta make money, get turnt.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

One reason I see for your squares turning into rectangles is that the CSS on your `.box` element defines a `px` value on the height while giving a `%` value for the width. Modifying your pen, and specifically the `.box` CSS to the following ensures that it is always a square. I tested by using the different viewport modes available in Chrome's developer console

```
.box {
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px;
  resize: vertical;
  width: 200px;
}
```

But alas, the whole layout is not responsive as the box shrinks on larger screen. 
Using media queries based on standard screen sizes (or by using bootstrap) and setting `px` or `em` based widths on the container can help result in a responsive layout

Comment: I appreciate your input @raghav710, but this does not answer my full question. I have created a completely responsive square before, but I can't seem to combine it with the vertical alignment

Comment: @FussinHussin thanks for the input. I'll see if i find a better answer